# Johnson-Lindenstrauss Lemma on $S^{d-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, metric-embeddings

Consider the Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma in the case where we can assume the $n$ input points $x_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ are actually located on the sphere 
$$S^{d-1}(r):=\{u=(u_1,\ldots,u_{d}): u_1^2+\cdots+u_d^2=r\},$$
for some $r>0.$

How does this impact the conclusion of the theorem? In particular, can the upper and lower bounds
$$
(1-\varepsilon)\sqrt{k/d}~\left| x_i-x_j\right|^2\leq \left| f(x_i)-f(x_j)\right|^2 
\leq (1+\varepsilon)\sqrt{k/d}~\left| x_i-x_j\right|^2,
$$ 
which hold with probability at least $1-\frac{1}{n^{c-2}},$
with $f$ an orthogonal projection on a random $k-$dimensional subspace,
where $k=c \log n/\varepsilon^2,$ possibly be strengthened in this case?

Comment: For those who don't know this lemma: Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the worst-case configurations require dimension projection proportional to the one obtained by linear embeddings

http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~minilek/publications/papers/jl_tight.pdf

it's not possible to gain by restricting the points to the sphere. Furthermore, I believe in the proof of this paper the input points (except for the origin) are all unit vectors.

Answer (score 1):

By the (supposedly unpublished) result of Noga Alon cited in the paper of Dasgupta and Gupta, the answer is NO:

*Dasgupta, Sanjoy; Gupta, Anupam*, [**An elementary proof of a theorem of Johnson and Lindenstrauss**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/rsa.10073), Random Struct. Algorithms 22, No.1, 60-65 (2003). [ZBL1018.51010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1018.51010).